# Mysql connector/c Version >=6 on Windows XP

Tags: mysql, dll, windows-xp, mysql-connector

I have to "downgrade" an existing apllication running fine on windows 7.
When starting in on Windows XP (SP3) it crashes with the comment `The procedure entry point InitializeConditionVariable could not located in the dynamic library Kernel32.dll`.
Reading the [oracle forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?168,607366,607366)  tells that on needs `mysql.dll` in **Version <** 6.
But how to optain such a DLL? I'm not able to find it from the oracle website.
Are there official ressources?
Hi there, I need to push the question up. I'm sorry, I can't believe there is no one able to answer. The question is two weeks old. Any help over there?
And once again a need to push - two further weeks without any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dario, thank you for your helpful answer.
I did not mark it as an answer, as there is no guarantee, the dll is from mysql.
I asked at mysql and got the following answer (from Lenka Kasparova):
I asked my colleagues and got advised on following response:

```
=====
We offer archives of earlier versions of Connector/C from our download archive:
http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/

Unfortunately versions prior to 6.0 spans back quite far and is no longer supported for download.
=====
```

But inspired by that I found another solution: Visiting the page http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ I found a way to download `mysql-5.6.19-win32.zip` (MD5: a855f736a676bd9b50b1a9a8c1b73065) from the Generally Available (GA) Releases. This file contains the wanted `libmysql.dll`. [image: Details of libmysql.dll]
You can see the crc checksum `53010E33` for the filesize `4 432 384 B` in the screenshot:[image: CRC-Sum of libmysql.dll in 7zip]

For those, who do not want to download the big `.zip` (217 394 KB), feel free to ask me for the given DLL or search for that version on the net and be sure to compare the hashes. That should be a little bit more trustable.

Answer (score 1):

I am the guy who posted on the Oracle forum. This is the last Windows XP 32 bit compatible libmysql.dll I could find anywhere on the Internet.

You may find the DLL at [this URL](http://vertstudios.com/blog/libmysqldll-32-bit-download/).
The download link is working at the time I am posting this answer.

It's an unofficial, third party website, not endorsed by Oracle. I warmly encourage who downloads it to scan it for viruses etc.

Best regards,
dfumagalli